# WPF issue with a resizable / collapsible usercontrol

Tags: wpf, animation, resize, controls

I'm trying to create a usercontrol that can resize and collapse/expand (with an animation). The resizing stop working when I play the collapse/expand animation.

Complete test application can be found here: [App](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ary5Ds-s_09TogpFsL3XW9HmxRDz)

**EDIT**: here's the relevant code as requested

*MyControl.xaml:*

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" 
         d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid Background="#FF935E5E">
    <Thumb Width="8"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           Margin="0,0,-4,0"
           DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" 
           Cursor="SizeWE"/>
</Grid>
```

*MyControl.xaml.cs:*

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {

        public bool IsOpen
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(true, OnIsOpenChanged));

        private static void OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyControl control = d as MyControl;
            control.PlayAnimation();
        }



        public double OpenWidth
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(OpenWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OpenWidthProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OpenWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("OpenWidth", typeof(double), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(300d, OnOpenWidthChanged));

        private static void OnOpenWidthChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyControl control = d as MyControl;
            if (control.IsOpen)
                control.Width = control.OpenWidth;
        }



        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (IsOpen)
                Width = OpenWidth;
        }

        private void Thumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenWidth += e.HorizontalChange;
        }


        private void PlayAnimation()
        {
            DoubleAnimation sizeAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(IsOpen ? OpenWidth : 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
            sizeAnimation.EasingFunction = new CircleEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
            BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, sizeAnimation);

        }
    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="700">

<DockPanel>
    <local:MyControl IsOpen="{Binding ControlIsOpen}"
                     OpenWidth="{Binding ControlOpenWidth}"/>
    <Grid Background="Green">
        <Button Width="100"
                Height="20"
                Content="Test Animation" 
                Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs:*

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged


        private bool _ControlIsOpen = true;
        public bool ControlIsOpen
        {
            get => _ControlIsOpen;
            set
            {
                _ControlIsOpen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        private double _ControlOpenWidth = 300d;
        public double ControlOpenWidth
        {
            get => _ControlOpenWidth;
            set
            {
                _ControlOpenWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlIsOpen = !ControlIsOpen;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You should paste the key codes here so that others can quickly get the problem. That can also help these who has the same troubles.

Comment: Did you use story board? There is a Fill property that can be set to Hold of Stop. If you keep default Hold behavior then the DependencyProperty will be updated by storyboard even when final value is reached.

Comment: You mean to modify the property after the storyboard finished?

Comment: Just set it when you create the Storyboard in xaml or code behind https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have download your demo, but didn't not catch the problem. Which line of code din't work?

Comment: @Iron: the resizing of the red panel with the thumb is broken after collapse/expand of the panel with the button

Comment: @Dmitry: I try to change the fill behavior to Hold (changes nothing) and Stop, which just set the panel back to it's expand state after the collapse animation

Comment: Yep I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

The animation actually never stopsYou should specifiy FillBehavior to Stop. In this case the annimation will stop updating the property after the final value is reached.

```
    private void PlayAnimation()
    {
        DoubleAnimation sizeAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(IsOpen ? OpenWidth : 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
        sizeAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
        sizeAnimation.EasingFunction = new CircleEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
        sizeAnimation.Completed += OnAnimationCompleted;
        BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, sizeAnimation);

    }

    private void OnAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Width = IsOpen ? OpenWidth : 0;
    }
```

The default value is HoldEnd. And the storyboard will modify the Width untill it is not explicitly stopped.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx

Some more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-set-a-property-after-animating-it-with-a-storyboard

Comment: I went with the same solution :) Didn't know about the FillBehavior though, so thanks for this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to Dmitry idea, i've been able to solve it, by setting the fill behavior to stop and forcing to width to be either 0 or the open width:

```
private void PlayAnimation()
{
    DoubleAnimation sizeAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(IsOpen ? OpenWidth : 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
    sizeAnimation.EasingFunction = new CircleEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
    sizeAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
    sizeAnimation.Completed += (s, e) => Width = (IsOpen ? OpenWidth : 0);
    BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, sizeAnimation);

}
```

Thanks all :)